# Hide element depending on value of if/else statement not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Rails app that uses the [LinkedIn Javascript API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/sign-linkedin) to authenticate users. What I'd like to do is hide an element depending on whether the user is signed up or not. I've tried a few things:

- Put the code with the if/else statement at the bottom of the HTML before `</body>`
- Check to see if `document.cookie` is an empty string instead of a more specific if/else

However, neither of these has hidden the element. If I go into my browser's console and paste in my code after the page is finished rendering, the element hides. So I thought this was a JavaScript load issue, but I must be doing something wrong. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Here's the code I've tried, none of which works:

```
<%= content_for(:script_footer) do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    // if ($('span.IN-widget:contains("inSign in with LinkedIn")').length > 0) {
    //   $('#select').hide();
    // } else {
    //   $('#select').show();
    // }

    if (document.cookie == "") {
      $('#select').hide();
    } else {
      $('#select').show();
    }
  </script>
<% end %>
```

And my application layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>rdtrip</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= yield(:linked_in) %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>
<%= yield(:script_footer) %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your jquery/javascript code with:

```
$(function(){
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: Whoops, should've added that I tried that as well. Still doesn't work. Thanks though!

Comment: Agh, I got it. Just needed to clear my cookies. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript is executed before the DOM is ready, so it can't find `#select` yet.

Wrap it in either:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    // code
});
```

Or:

```
$(function() {
     // code
});
```